# How to change opkg configuration

Tags: openwrt

Everything started from the need to install vsftpd. It's supposed to be very easy, just run opkg install vsftpd but it didn't work. I spent a while until understood why it doesn't find it. It turned out that /etc/opkg/distfeeds.conf contains only these two lines

src/gz openwrt_core http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/targets/x86/generic/packages
src/gz openwrt_base http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/packages/i386_pentium4/base

I build for x86 VM. As I understand this configuration file shows opkg where to look for the packages. vsftpd resides in ......./i386_pentium4/packages. How to add this URL to the source so that after the build and installation of the image this configuration file would contain this line and opkg install vsftpd would work?

Answer (score 1):

link: https://git.openwrt.org/?p=openwrt/openwrt.git;a=blob;f=package/system/opkg/files/opkg.conf;h=d8d3a2d693d8adf7249172188a23a44a6d6f25f3;hb=ec428bccadd655ace750b47f23f933dc3d05ebfe

add your configuare to "/package/system/opkg/files/opkg.conf"

and compile firmware again.

---

use command "opkg search /etc/opkg.conf" to find which package contain /etc/opkg.conf